# django website working, but django manage.py cannot connect to db

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to run a django migration to update my database, but "manage.py migrate" can't connect to my postgresql db. The odd thing is: my django website (which is exactly the same code) is working including connecting to the db.

Error messages:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.xxxxxx"?
```

and

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
        Is the server running locally and accepting 
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Workaround: Change HOST variable to either localhost or 127.0.0.1 .

see:  https://community.webfaction.com/questions/21072/django-website-working-but-django-managepy-cannot-connect-to-db

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. If the link you posted has worthy information on the matters, please copy relevant information here (assuming the licence allows) or summarize it along with the link. We never know when the link might become invalid.

Comment: @spectras I'm more concerned about Google finding my answer so that others can benefit from it.  The link points to a more information.  I just include this question and answer on stackoverflow so others can find it.  The answer was not on stackoverflow when I was facing this problem, and I felt very lucky and appreciative when someone figured it out.  So, I'm passing on the good karma.